# How do you query Tableaus GraphQL using C#

Tags: c#, graphql, httpwebrequest, tableau-api

(Question also asked [here](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000K5LmHSAV/how-do-you-query-graphqi-using-c).)

I am attempting to connect to and query Tableau via GraphQL using C#. I have been trying for a while now, and keep hitting a wall when sending the query.

I am creating a httpWebRequest to send the query using the following method.

The variables passed in are:

```
string Url = MyTableauServer/api/metadata/graphql

string Method = "POST"

string payload = """query TestName1   {  databaseServersConnection(first: 10)     {    totalCount,    pageInfo{endCursor,hasNextPage,}    nodes      {      connectionType,      __typename,      hostName,      name,      port,      isEmbedded,      tables        {        id,        schema,        name,        columns          {          id,          name          }        }      }    }  }"""
```

The AuthToken is obtained by querying the REST API. The authenticated user has permissions to be able to perform any and all of the required actions.

```
    public static string SendJsonWebRequest(string Url, string Method, string payload, string AuthToken)

    {

      try

      {

        string response;

        //encode the json payload  

        byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Uri.EscapeDataString(payload));

        //set the system to ignore certificate errors because Tableau server has an invalid cert.  

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

 

        //Create the web request and add the json payload  

        HttpWebRequest wc = WebRequest.CreateHttp(Url) as HttpWebRequest;

        wc.Method = Method;

        wc.PreAuthenticate = true;

        wc.Headers.Add($"X-Tableau-Auth: {AuthToken}, content-type: application/json, accept: application/json");

        wc.ContentLength = buf.Length;

        wc.GetRequestStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);

 

        try

        {

          //Send the web request and parse the response into a string  

//this is as far as i get

          HttpWebResponse wr = wc.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

          Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();

          StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

          response = readStream.ReadToEnd();

          receiveStream.Close();

          readStream.Close();

          wr.Close();

        }

        catch (WebException we)

        {

          //Catch failed request and return the response code  

          if (we.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)

          {

            WebResponse resp = we.Response;

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))

            {

              response = sr.ReadToEnd();

            }

          }

          else

          {

            response = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode.ToString();

          }

        }

        return response;

      }

      catch (Exception E)

      {

        logger.Trace($"- ERROR - Error in SendWebRequest. System says: {E.Message}");

        return E.Message;

      }

    }
```

The most recent error i am getting is **"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."** being returned at the following line:

```
HttpWebResponse wr = wc.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Any ideas or assistance would be greatly appreciated

**------------------------------------------------------------**

**Update:**

using Fiddler i get the following response.

```
{

  "timestamp": 1600939439846,

  "status": 401,

  "error": "Unauthorized",

  "message": "User is not authenticated",

  "path": "/relationship-service-war/graphql"

}
```

I am authenticated, Authentication token is valid and is passed in the headers.

**------------------------------------------------------**

**Update:**

Adding the code for authentication. logged in user is a server admin so no issues with access rights.

```
    public static string TabLogIn(string User, string Pass, string ContURL = "")
    {
        string response = "";
        try
        {
            using (XmlWriter loginxml = XmlWriter.Create("signin.xml"))
            {
                loginxml.WriteStartDocument();
                loginxml.WriteStartElement("tsRequest");
                loginxml.WriteStartElement("credentials");
                loginxml.WriteAttributeString("name", User);
                loginxml.WriteAttributeString("password", Pass);
                loginxml.WriteStartElement("site");
                loginxml.WriteAttributeString("contentUrl", ContURL);
                loginxml.WriteEndElement();
                loginxml.WriteEndElement();
                loginxml.WriteEndElement();
                loginxml.WriteEndDocument();
            }
            XElement myxml = XElement.Load("signin.xml");
            string myxmlstring = myxml.ToString();

            //send payload to routine to make the web request  
            string URL = $@"{Enums.Server}/api/{Enums.APIVersion34}/auth/signin";


            //Send the above url, the POST method, and the XML Payload string to create the web request  
            var infotl = SendWebRequest(URL, "POST", myxmlstring);

            response = infotl;
            File.Delete("signin.xml");

            return response;
        }
        catch(Exception E)
        {
            logger.Trace($"- ERROR - Error in TabLogIn. System says: {E.Message}");
            return response;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (File.Exists("signin.xml"))
            {
                File.Delete("signin.xml");
            }
        }
    }

    static string SendWebRequest(string Url, string Method, string payload)
    {
        try
        {
            string response;
            //encode the XML payload  
            byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
            //set the system to ignore certificate errors because Tableau server has an invalid cert.  
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

            //Create the web request and add the XML payload  
            HttpWebRequest wc = WebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
            wc.Method = Method;
            wc.ContentType = "text/xml";
            wc.ContentLength = buf.Length;
            wc.GetRequestStream().Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);

            try
            {
                //Send the web request and parse the response into a string  
                HttpWebResponse wr = wc.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                response = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                receiveStream.Close();
                readStream.Close();
                wr.Close();
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                //Catch failed request and return the response code  
                response = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode.ToString();
            }
            return response;
        }
        catch(Exception E)
        {
            logger.Trace($"- ERROR - Error in SendWebRequest. System says: {E.Message}");
            return E.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Double check if you're requesting a token from the correct Tableau Site (if you have multiple sites). Also what permissions does user have and can you share the code where you request the token?

Comment: Thats a good point. I have to authenticate against a site, but the GraphQL documentation for Tableau doesnt specify how you limit your query to just a site.

Comment: In the authentication part when you're getting the token you define the site, in the XML request body.

https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_auth.htm

Comment: i know that part, but when i'm querying the GraphQL API there is no way to specify the site that i am querying

Comment: So i get the authentication key from REST API, easy. I authenticate against "Site1", i now have a key that is authenticated for Site1 only.
Using this key to access the GraphQL API, there is no way to tell the API that i am querying Site1. I am assuming that it may be trying to run the query against all sites, and failing because i am only authenticated against Site1.

Comment: I know requesting the token works, as i have a whole automation system that has been running for a few years now querying all sites via the REST API, but ill add the code in an edit.

Comment: Yeah, don't doubt it! I'm looking in my end and there's no place where I add the site ID when querying the graphql and it's working fine. The main difference I have with yours other than the language is the API Version. I'm using  3.5

That might be the trick since 3.4 was released on 2019.2 which was before graphql

Comment: tried with 3.5 and 3.6, still getting the "user is not authenticated" error.

Comment: Ok, so I'm running out of ideas here. Last shot in the dark. Can you head over to your server settings and check if you have the Automatic Access to Metadata turned on?

Comment: Automatic Access to Metadata about Databases and Tables - Check box is checked.

Comment: what language are you using to connect?